# how to create a login page for a website using html, css, javascript and php & mysql as backend?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am new to web development. I want to develop the front page of my website through which users can enter their username and password and login to their accounts. How should I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make your own implementation but there are a lot of security risks to worry about. Particularly things like [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There are frameworks you can use to implement login pages that take care of the security for you. You just need to find the one that works best for you. [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.multiuser.authentication.html) is one example of a PHP compatible framework that does authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a decent starting point if you really want to write your own log-in/out routines..

https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Log-In-Form-Log-Out-Script-Cookies-Sessions-User-Profile

All that is lacking on that page is the layout of the database.